# Is it true that $(1+o(1))^\frac{1}{2} = (1 + o(1))?$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I think its true that $(1+o(1))^\frac{1}{2} = (1 + o(1))$ but I'm not sure if my argument is correct.

I would appreciate if someone told me if my argument is correct, or if someone provided a different argument of the same result (if its true).

We can assume (I think?) that $|o(1)| < 1$ and so we can apply the binomial theorem. I'm a little hesitant about this step, since typically the binomial theorem is applied to something like $(1+x)^n$ for concrete $x$ but $o(1)$ seems more mysterious and less concrete.

But anyway, applying the binomial theorem:

$(1 + o(1))^\frac{1}{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}o(1) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\frac{o(1)^2}{2!} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}\frac{o(1)^3}{3!} + \dots$

Observe the series is absolutely convergent since the absolute value of the degree $k$ term is at most $o(1)^k$.

Hence $(1 + o(1))^\frac{1}{2} \leq 1 + o(1) + o(1)^2 + o(1)^3 + \dots = 1 + \frac{o(1)}{1 - o(1)} = 1 + o(1)\frac{1}{1 - o(1)} = 1 + o(1)$ since we can assume $o(1) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and so we can assume that $\frac{1}{1 - o(1)} \leq 2$.

I think my main difficulty with this is being uncomfortable performing algebraic manipulations or applying binomial formula with expression like $o(1)$. Can I justify those things by treating it like a number that is as small as I like?

Comment: "[I'm] uncomfortable performing algebraic manipulations... with expression[s] like $o(1)$" General tip: then make your notation more explicit. Example for this problem: if $f\in o(1)$ then, for constant $q\ne0$, prove $(1+f)^q-1\in o(1)$ (hint: first prove $\frac{(1+f)^q-1}{f}\sim q$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_n \to 0$ then $\sqrt {1+a_n}-1=\frac {a_n} {\sqrt {1+a_n}+1}\to \frac 0 {1+1}=0$, so the answer is YES.

Answer (score -1):

Since the $o$-notations with equal symbols sometimes are confusing, I think it would be better to state the equation more explicitly.

Specifically, $(1+o(1))^\frac{1}{2} = (1 + o(1))$ means

> Given $f(n): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if for any $c > 0$, there exists $N_0$ s.t. $n > N_0 \Rightarrow 1 - c \leq f(n) \leq 1 + c$, then $g(n) = f^{1/2}(n)$ satisfies that for any $c > 0$, there exists $N_1$ s.t. $n > N_1 \Rightarrow 1 - c \leq g(n) \leq 1 + c$.

And it is true since $N_1(c) = N_0(c)$ suffices.